# Unable to locate package ros-lunar-desktop-full

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using the instructions at http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation/Debian titled "Debian install of ROS Lunar", I am able to successfully complete the steps up through 1.3.  On step 1.3 I had to install dirmngr, but was able to complete the step.

In step 1.4, I successfully executed `sudo apt-get update`.

In step 1.4, I tried to execute `sudo apt-get install ros-lunar-desktop-full`, but it failed with the error "Unable to locate package ros-lunar-desktop-full".

I am running Debian 9.1 Stretch on a 64 bit AMD based PC.

The command `apt-cache search ros-lunar` does not return anything.

I am pretty new to Linux, could somebody please help me understand what I have done wrong?

Thank you,

Randall

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271419/unable-to-locate-package-ros-lunar-desktop-full/) by [Randall Brodka](https://answers.ros.org/users/32006/randall-brodka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-09-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-25**:
According to [status_page/ros_lunar_ds.html?q=desktop](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_lunar_ds.html?q=desktop), the `desktop_full` pkg should be available on Debian Stretch, but only for AMD64. Can you install any other ROS pkgs? Try `ros-lunar-ros-base`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did not find a solution for this problem, but I resolved it another way.

I originally installed Ubuntu on some old hardware to give ROS a try.  I experienced lots of trouble installing Ubuntu and keeping it running, so I replaced the install with Debian.  Debian installed cleanly and worked without issue.  I then tried to install ROS and ran into this problem.

Since my hardware was old and low powered, I decided to build a new computer.  I tried installing Ubuntu on the new computer, and it went smooth as silk.  I then installed ROS with no problems.

I'm now going through the tutorials.

Thanks to all who read my problem and offered suggestions!

---

Originally posted by [Randall Brodka](https://answers.ros.org/users/32006/randall-brodka/) with karma: 16 on 2017-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-26**:
I wouldn't say this is a *solution*, but as long as you're happy we're ok.